# How can I have a junit @Beforeclass && @Afterclass in my TestSuite interface?

Tags: java, junit, interface

**Problem:** I have a custom Interface for a *TestSuite*.

```
public interface TestSuite {

  abstract void setupRestAssuredForSuite();
  abstract void restoreDatabase();
  abstract void executeSuitePreparation();
  abstract void executeSuiteTearDown();

}
```

How can I have my interface contain @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotations from junit and my implementations of the TestSuite interface to acknowledge those?  Should I be doing this another way completely? I am curious to know if such a thing is possible with interfaces.

do I need to write the annotations manually in every class which implements TestSuite? or can I have the `executeSuitePreparation();` and `executeSuiteTearDown();` methods running without the annotations because they somehow exist in TestSuite itself and I just need to implement the code behind setup/teardown.

```
public class Foo extends Bar implements TestSuite
```

To my knowledge the @Beforeclass and @Afterclass methods must be static.

Is this a silly way of approaching the situation? Could you recommend a different way of doing it if that is the case.

Comment: Why don't you just create an abstract class and tag the methods @Before?

Comment: I need to extend Bar, am I missing something there, how could I extend this new abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use interfaces as mixins. Interfaces are not mixins.

Probably the best you can do is to write static methods in your interface that do the required setup:

```
public interface TestSuite {

  abstract void setupRestAssuredForSuite();
  ...


  static SomeReturn setup()
  {
      Database database = new Database();
      ...
      return database;
  }

  static void teardown(SomeType foo)
  {
      foo.reset();
  }
}
```

Then in your concrete implementations you can do:

```
public class Foo extends Bar implements TestSuite
{
    private static Foo foo;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass()
    {
        foo = TestSuite.setup();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass()
    {
        TestSuite.teardown(foo);
    }
}
```

I would *strongly* encourage you to re-think whether you need to use inheritance in your tests. It seems like a code smell to me, and indicates that your tests are perhaps not focused enough.